# Which neural network algorithms can be used to map motion vectors in image processing?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, image-processing

I'm working on finding out the motion vectors of objects in images. The inputs are the images of objects in motion. The outputs of neural network are the object name, direction of object vector and prediction of next vector change.

There are different 3D ConvNets I'm considering as a baseline like ReMotENet. I would appreciate if you would recommend any interesting papers in MoCap domain and any existing neural networks performing similar task.